# undefined value return from node.js javascript class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have declared class which generates the records and simply return it but it is returning undefined.

```
var classObj = new User();
var user = classObj.generateUserResponse(val1,mode);
console.log(user) //undefined

User.prototype.generateUserResponse = function (userid, mode) {

     conn.query('select * from users where user_id = ?', [userid], function (err, user) {
              if(mode == 'true') {
                   var genObj = new CustomerJSON();
                   userObj = genObj.generateUserCustomer(user);
                   console.log(userObj) // displays the value
                   return userObj;
              } else {
                // do something else
}
    })
```

What I am doing above is creating a new class and passing a user object in a new class for further processing. I can console log and can see the data but when I return userObj it displays undefine.

Comment: Your `return userObj;` statement is returning a value for the function in the conn.query line.

Comment: @IrkenInvader, it means it should be outside the conn.query statement?

Comment: Your prototype method is not returning anything. The only `return` you have is for the `conn.query` callback. What do you want `generateUserResponse` to return? It looks like its asynchronous.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, just meant that your function is returning undefined because you never return anything in the outer function.  Maybe conn.query returns a value so you can just add return to the start of that line?

Comment: @NicolasMoise. conn.query is asynchronus but how to return a value of the prototype method then?

Comment: you could `return conn.query(....)`, or whatever you want. Really, you should ask yourself what do YOU want that function to return? Does it even make sense for that function to return anything? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right, because the invoked asynchronous function calls the callback (which returns the object to noone) after you log the object to console.
The function `generateUserResponse` returns no value.

Solution: make the required actions in the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Pavel is correct. Your function is asynchronous. You need a callback. Try something like this:

```
var classObj = new User();
classObj.generateUserResponse(val1, mode, function(userObj) {
  console.log(userObj);
});

User.prototype.generateUserResponse = function(userid, mode, callback) {
  //you could decide to return conn.query here and handle it differently above
  conn.query('select * from users where user_id = ?', [userid], function(err, user) {
      if (mode == 'true') {
          var genObj = new CustomerJSON();
          userObj = genObj.generateUserCustomer(user);
          console.log(userObj) // displays the value
          return callback(userObj);
      } else {
          // do something else 
          //THEN
          return callback(userObj);
      }
  })

});
```

Or you could `return conn.query(...` and handle the promise it returns based on whatever library you're using.